# Would one be pushing as much as their weight with this machine?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, free-body-diagram

I was looking at the following machine in the video below, and was wondering, would one be pushing as much as their weight?
https://youtu.be/a_CGlAnxO5c

It looks sort of like a chest press machine but doesn't have weights attached - only attached to the chair so they are pushing the chair up.
**Would one, then, effectively be pushing/lifting as much as they weigh with this machine?**

Also, this may be unrelated to the question at hand based on the responses people give, but other anonymous people on a different platform mentioned something about having 'arms at a perpendicular angle' affecting this. If possible, may I please have this explained as well?

Comment: I wrote an answer to the main question, but also to directly address the "perpendicular angle" thing in your last paragraph - No that doesn't matter. I can't think of any reason how it changes the analysis that he's pushing perpendicular to gravity. The force he pushes is transferred to his butt through the machine.

Answer (score 2):

> I was looking at the following machine in the video below, and was
> wondering, would one be pushing as much as their weight?

His pushing force is less than his weight due to the mechanical advantage of the machine.

If you look closely at the video you will see that the vertical movement of his arms is greater than the vertical movement of his seat. In order for the positive work being done by him (his upward force times times its upward vertical displacement) be equal to the negative work done by gravity on him (its downward force times its upward vertical displacement) his upward force must be less than his weight.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. for some reason your answer didn't show before I wrote mine. Mine is mostly redundant, but I'll leave it because I made a picture for it.

Comment: @AXensen no problem. They complement each other +1

Answer (score 2):

His arms move a longer distance than he is lifted. Therefore the force he needs to push with is lower than his weight. There is a mechanical advantage. Much like to lift the rock in this picture, the person would need to push down with less force than the weight of the rock, but they would need to push through a longer distance, so that work (distance pushed times force of pushing) done by the person equals the work done on the rock.
[image].